# Logout specific user by admin Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

As a admin i want to logout specific user from application.

I tried following code to make user log out from application.

```
Auth::logout();
```

But instead of logging out that specific user it makes admin logout.
I am getting session id from server, now I am confuse how can I pass that session id to clear that specific users session so that specific user gets log out.

Comment: You generally cannot do this but it depends on how you save users' session. You might be able to invalidate the user's session by deleting from the server's session storage. It might take some time to identify which session belongs to the user you want to be logged out though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as all Auth:logout do is to delete the session cookie.

Of course you can't access cookies of other users.

Depending on your session driver, you may be able to invalidate the session server side.

For example if the driver is database, it can be as simple as a DB query to delete the session id (but well, you'll have to parse ALL sessions payloads to find the correct user id)

One simpler way to go is to add a session_token field to your user table. On login, you generate a random value and store it both in session and in database. Then in a middleware, check whenever the DB's session_token match with the one in the session.

To logout an user, simply reset the token in the DB and here we go !

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$userToLogout = User::find(1);  // Any userId you want to logout
Auth::setUser($userToLogout);
Auth::logout();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column in your users table called `force_logout` for instance. Then on every request (in your authentication middleware), check this `force_logout`. Then you can log the user out with `Auth::logout();` IF `force_logout` is `1`.

So if you wanna log any user out, you just need to make `force_logout` of the user `1`.